# Spring Boot: object in input to the controller with error on the fields

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, http

I am developing a Java backend application using **Spring Boot**. My controller needs to receive this type of object as input with an HTTP POST call:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Input {

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String fiscalCode;
    
}
```

obviously these data arrive thanks to a JSON made like this:

```
{
   "name":"John",
   "surname":"Smith",
   "fiscalCode":"XXXXXXXXX"
}
```

This is an example of a controller handling POST containing this body:

```
@PostMapping(produces = { "application/json" })
public ResponseEntity<Object> myController(@RequestBody Input myInput) {
   // code....
}
```

The question is: how can I elegantly (**without using a switch case or a series of if-else**) detect all fields that are "" or `null` in my `myInput` object, and return a string that warns for example that "`name`, `surname` fields missing"?

What is the best way to do this? I've heard it's okay to use `@ControllerAdvice`, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Add `spring-boot-starter-validation`.. Add `@NotEmpty`/`@NotNull` to your fields. Add `@Valid` next to `@RequestBody`... Restart application...

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `@Validate` annotation.

e.g. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-validation